# How to add Splide Grid extention in Svelte

Tags: svelte, splidejs

The Svelte Splide documentation doesn't show an example of how to add an extension.
https://splidejs.com/integration/svelte-splide/

The Grid extension documentation is here:
https://splidejs.com/extensions/grid/

I've been trying this way:

```
import { Splide, SplideSlide } from '@splidejs/svelte-splide';
import { Grid } from '@splidejs/splide-extension-grid';

<Splide …
 options={ {
  fixedHeight: 380,
  gap: 20,
  arrows: false,
  grid: {
   rows: 3,
   cols: 3,
  },
} }
</Splide>
```

Can anyone give me an example of how to add it?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an example of how to add extensions in the **Video** demonstration in the documentation:
https://github.com/Splidejs/svelte-splide/blob/master/examples/src/routes/components/VideoExample.svelte

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://splidejs.com/integration/svelte-splide/#extensions) you can register the extension like this:

```js
<Splide
     options={ {
      fixedHeight: 380,
      gap: 20,
      arrows: false,
      grid: {
       rows: 3,
       cols: 3,
        },
      }}
extensions= { {Grid} }
</Splide>
```